# ng-content is not being rendered with ng-if

Tags: angular

I m trying to use ng-content with *ngIf. i have a condition that if there is a config object, i want to render the content of ng-content with a wrapper div but if there is no config object than i would like to render the content without a wrapper div. Somehow on one condition, its being always rendered but on the other condition, ng-content is not being rendered. Any ideas what i m doing wrong ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'aurora-page-sub-header',
  templateUrl: './page-sub-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-sub-header.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PageSubHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  collapse: boolean = false;
  @Input() conf?: any;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

HTML

```
 <div *ngIf="conf">
        <div  class="aurora-c-page-sub-header-container">
            <h3 class="aurora-c-page-sub-header-search">{{ 'ADVANCED_PAYMENTS_CONTROL.INQUIRIES_SEARCH.SEARCH' | translate }}</h3>
            <h3 class="aurora-c-page-sub-header-notes">{{ 'ADVANCED_PAYMENTS_CONTROL.INQUIRIES_SEARCH.ACTION_NOTES' | translate }}</h3>
            <a (click)="collapse=!collapse">Collapse</a>
        </div>
        <div class="aurora-c-page-sub-header" [hidden]="collapse">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!conf">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
```

UPDATE (still not working:/)

```
<ng-template #projected>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>

<div *ngIf="conf">
    <div  class="aurora-c-page-sub-header-container">
        <h3 class="aurora-c-page-sub-header-search">{{ 'AURORA.ADVANCED_PAYMENTS_CONTROL.INQUIRIES_SEARCH.SEARCH' | translate }}</h3>
        <h3 class="aurora-c-page-sub-header-notes">{{ 'AURORA.ADVANCED_PAYMENTS_CONTROL.INQUIRIES_SEARCH.ACTION_NOTES' | translate }}</h3>
        <a (click)="collapse=!collapse">Collapse</a>
    </div>
    <div class="aurora-c-page-sub-header" [hidden]="collapse">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="projected"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>

<div  *ngIf="!!conf">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="projected"> </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: wanna ask one thing. when there's no config object, config is an empty object or null? If it's an empty object, it will render first div. Object's logical state is always `true`

Comment: its an optional input. so i assume null

Comment: There's an extra `!` in the UPDATE's "not" condition. Try changing `*ngIf="!!conf"` to `*ngIf="!conf"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-content` can only exist once, you need to wrap it inside a `ng-template` that will only be displayed one time

When I faced this, I wrap the projected content in a `ng-template`:

```html
<ng-template #projected>
  <ng-content/>
</ng-template>
```

Then, I am invoking the template from my wraper which will display one or the other parent element depending on the condition:

```html
<div *ngIf="template === '1'">
  <span>In template 1 - </span>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="projected" />
</div>

<div *ngIf="template === '2'">
  <span>In template 2 - </span>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="projected" />
</div>
```

Here is [a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkkjfv?file=src%2Fmain.ts) of that example running

Comment: Updated my code in the question. still no success.. :/